# Margin: 0 auto; not centering div with float:left

Tags: html, css

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/feyv4o4u/

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;position:relative;float:left;margin:0 auto" >
</div>
```

I have a division as presented in the fiddle above that cant be aligned in the center.

I have used `float:left` for the division so that the division width will fit the content as opposed to having 100% width.

How can I align a division as such to the center? 
**Note**: Division width must fit content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float: left` is designed to move an element to the left and let the content that follows it move up beside it.

If you don't want that. Don't use `float: left`.

You can get a shrink-wrapping effect with `display: table`.

Answer (score 2):

It will not work in this way, istead of `float: left`, use `display: table`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xnaz4Ld/)

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/feyv4o4u/2/)

`margin:auto` wont make the element centered if you use `float` property. One little hack to solve this problem will be to replace `float:left` with `display:inline-block;`

`display:inline-block;` will make the `div` look like a floated `div`. Now, to make it centered wrap the element in a `div` which has a style `text-align:center`.

Updated HTML

```
<div class="centerd_div">

  <div style="border:1px solid black;position:relative;display:inline-block;margin:auto;text-align: left;" class="align-center">
    <div class="align-center" style="margin-top:2%;"><a style="font-size: 20px;color:darkgray;padding-right:33px" class="inline-block switch-workout">Workout</a><a style="color:darkgray; font-size: 20px;" class="inline-block" id="switch-calender">Calender</a></div>

    <a id="switch-border" style="font-size: 20px;color:black;border-top:1px solid black;" class="inline-block">Workout</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.centerd_div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

### Snippet

```css
.centerd_div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerd_div">

  <div style="border:1px solid black;position:relative;display:inline-block;margin:auto;text-align: left;" class="align-center">
    <div class="align-center" style="margin-top:2%;"><a style="font-size: 20px;color:darkgray;padding-right:33px" class="inline-block switch-workout">Workout</a><a style="color:darkgray; font-size: 20px;" class="inline-block" id="switch-calender">Calender</a></div>

    <a id="switch-border" style="font-size: 20px;color:black;border-top:1px solid black;" class="inline-block">Workout</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin: auto` deosn't work with `float`. You can add a parent and use `display: flex; justify-content: center;`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div style="border:1px solid black;position:relative;" class="align-center">
    <div class="align-center" style="margin-top:2%;"><a style="font-size: 20px;color:darkgray;padding-right:33px" class="inline-block switch-workout">Workout</a><a style="color:darkgray; font-size: 20px;" class="inline-block" id="switch-calender">Calender</a></div>

    <a id="switch-border" style="font-size: 20px;color:black;border-top:1px solid black" class="inline-block">Workout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can make the child `display: inline-block; text-align: left;` then use `text-align: center` on the parent

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div style="border:1px solid black;position:relative;display: inline-block;text-align: left;" class="align-center">
    <div class="align-center" style="margin-top:2%;"><a style="font-size: 20px;color:darkgray;padding-right:33px" class="inline-block switch-workout">Workout</a><a style="color:darkgray; font-size: 20px;" class="inline-block" id="switch-calender">Calender</a></div>

    <a id="switch-border" style="font-size: 20px;color:black;border-top:1px solid black" class="inline-block">Workout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```